# How to check If the smart contract support an interface?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, interfaces, royalties

I have token contract which implements `IERC2981` interface and I've overridden the `supportsInterface` function like so.

```
function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC721,
        IERC165) returns (bool) {
    return (interfaceId == type(IERC2981).interfaceId || super.supportsInterface(interfaceId));
}
```

How will I check or call the `supportsInterface` function from another contract? let's say from my sales contract I want to check If the token contract supports `IERC2981` If its does call the `royaltyInfo` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the `address` of your target contract and want to enforce that the `IERC2981` is supported you would do the following:

```js
require(
  IEIP165(target).supportsInterface(type(IERC2981).interfaceId),
  "Contract does not support IERC2981" interface.
);
```

The `IEIP165` interface can be found in the [OpenZepplin contracts](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/introspection/IERC165.sol).

Answer (score 0):

What if the contract does not support ERC165, i.e. the supportsInterface function does not exist; will it revert?

I'm looking for a safe way to check interface support without reverting, eg:

```
 if ( IERC165(target).supportsInterface(0x2a55205a) ) {
   ...
 } else {...}
```

Comment: OpenZeppelin has a library dedicated for this purpose (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/introspection/ERC165Checker.sol)